# Error with ofstream and ifstream being unidentified in Visual Studio 19

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program using files and when I use ofstream or ifstream, Visual Studio says that ofstream and ifstream is undefined. Can someone please explain this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ofstream file("Test.txt", std::ios::app);
       file << "File successfully made\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Even this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ofstream` is in the namespace `std`, so you need to specify that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file("Test.txt", std::ios::app); // ofstream -> std::ofstream
       file << "File successfully made\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason in other ides this isn't required